# Tracking events of a control

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Is there a way to know which .net events are being called on a control in real time?

I'm not talking about "win32" event from spy++. I'm looking for events like BackColorChanged, CausesValidationChanged, ect.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

one method would be to have your program write a log entry when an event is fired

and save that log when the program closes

Comment: I had a 3rd party control with a lot of event and I wanted to know which one was called when I clicked on it, handling all the events would've taken a lot of time.